# Using a Loop to print copies, Python

Tags: python, winapi

I have a simple python script that prints pdf's within a folder. I want the user to be able to make the script print multiple copies of the pdf's.

Here is the script:

```
import arcpy, glob, win32api, os

pdfLoc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Loop through pdf directory and print from pdf
for pdfname in glob.glob(os.path.join(pdfLoc, "*.pdf")):

    fullpath = os.path.join(pdfLoc, pdfname)
    #print filename
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdfname, None, ".", 0)


del fullpath
del pdfname
del pdfLoc
```

I'm thinking something simple like another for loop to read the number of copies and make it loop that many times (i.e. if the user wants 3 copies, the loop will read this and loop 2 times through the print loop)

I hope this makes sense. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very close to what you'd want to do. This example gets the number of copies from an optional extra command line parameter, then prints that many copies of each document:

```
import sys, glob, win32api, os

pdfLoc = sys.argv[1]
try:
    copies = int(sys.argv[2])
except:
    copies = 1

for pdfname in glob.glob(os.path.join(pdfLoc, "*.pdf")):
    fullpath = os.path.join(pdfLoc, pdfname)
    for copy in range(copies):
        win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdfname, None, ".", 0)
```

Comment: @Mike Happy to help! Now study up so you can help the next guy asking a question. :-)